# El Capitan GM and USB passthrough

Tags: usb, virtualbox, macos

After updgrading to El Capitan GM, I noticed that usb passthrough no longer works in VirtualBox, and this seems to be occuring for everyone. I have found several threads on VirtualBox forums addressing this, but they are all for earlier beta releases of El Capitan. It seems like a change in IOKit is causing the problem.

Version info:

- VirtualBox 5.0.4
- Host OS: OS X 10.11 15A282a
- Guest OS: Kali Linux (uname -r: 4.0.0-kali1-amd64)

So, I am wondering whether anyone here are having the same issue, and can offer some insight, or elaborate on how they may have fixed the issue.

Link to thread on VirtualBox forums concerning this issue:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=69179

Comment: Yikes - one Oracle employee says "Short version: If you need it working now, go yell at Apple. Otherwise wait." Hopefully someone will have a more intelligent answer here.

Comment: @bmike My thoughts exactly.

Comment: At the end of the referenced forum thread users claim 5.0.6 is working. It still doesn't work for me, at least not with Apple Internal Memory Card Reader device. How about you?